# Accessing Environment Variables Within The app.yaml File

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I was wondering if it possible to access local environment variables within the `app.yaml` file of an app engine project and then use those in python code?

For example, say in my `.bash_profile` I have two variables defined:

```
export GOOGLE_EMAIL=email@gmail.com
export GOOGLE_PASSWORD=password
```

Inside my `app.yaml` file, I try to access them like this:

```
env_variables:
  GOOGLE_EMAIL: {$GOOGLE_EMAIL}
  GOOGLE_PASSWORD: {$GOOGLE_PASSWORD}
```

And then in the python code, I again try to access them by invoking the following:

```
import os

email = os.environ.get("GOOGLE_EMAIL")
password = os.environ.get("GOOGLE_PASSWORD")
```

Is this possible and did I just screw up? I believe I had this working last week, but it's fallen apart as of recently. Any help would be great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can **define** variables in your `app.yaml` file which you can later access in your programs via `os.environ`, see https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Python_app_yaml_Defining_environment_variables:

[image]

Comment: I know I can just put the variables in the app.yaml file... but the issue is, I want them to remain hidden from other contributors. In a way, I wanted to just 'proxy' my local variables so that they are inaccessible to others. I'd like to access my local variables, not create new ones I suppose.

Comment: I don't think that would work when deployed on GAE since your local vars wouldn't be included in your deployment.